# Which Christian denominations do NOT believe that Jesus existed prior to his conception?

Tags: christology, denomination-survey, incarnation

Basically the title: Which Christian denominations do NOT believe that Jesus existed in some manner before his conception? If there are way too many, a reasonable answer listing the most notable ones would be a fair compromise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Iglesia ni Cristo](https://iglesianicristo.net/) (Church of Christ) has ~2.3 million adherents and is the 3rd largest religious group in the Philippines.

> "But we do not subscribe to the belief that Christ is a God-Man or
> both God and man. He is man in nature according to His own testimony
> (John 8:40) and the teachings of His Apostles (I Tim. 2:5; Matt.
> 1:18)." [The Lord Jesus Christ](https://iglesianicristo.net/beliefs/the-lord-jesus-christ/)

More specifically, a letter to the editor of Iglesia ni Cristo's publication God's Message [asked](https://www.studyiglesianicristo.com/Questions/interesting-questions-31.html)

> "Why is it that your  religion does not teach these three basic
> doctrines (divinity, pre-existence, incarnation) about Christ?"

and the answer was in part

> "What is spoken of in John 1:1, 14 as being with God in the beginning
> is the "Word." Hence, in order to understand the real message of John
> 1:1, 14, we should first clarify the meaning of the term "Word." Does
> it  really  refer to a 'pre-existent Christ' as others allege? No.
> The Holy  Scriptures prove instead that the "Word"  refers to God's
> "promise" to send His  Son, which He "announced" before[.]"

[Christadelphians](https://christadelphian.org.au/) number ~60,000 adherents.

> "Jesus Christ is a man, Christadelphians say, not God. He did not
> exist prior to his earthly incarnation." [Christadelphian beliefs and
> practices](https://www.learnreligions.com/christadelphian-beliefs-and-practices-700276)

[Church of God, General Conference](https://coggc.org/) has ~5,000 adherents.

> "Jesus is the Christ. Existing from his mother’s womb, he is the
> virgin born son of God (Luke 1:34-35, Gal. 4:4)." [Our Beliefs](https://coggc.org/discover/our-beliefs/)

I'm sure there are more, but verifying non-English churches becomes tricky.

[BiblicalUnitarian.com](https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/) and the [Revised English Version](https://www.revisedenglishversion.com/) Bible translation (including commentary and appendices) is by the [Spirit and Truth Fellowship](https://www.stfonline.org/), a non-denominational ministry. I do not know the number of people affiliated with the organization (I presume it is small), but the resources they provide seem the most comprehensive and easily accessible of Biblical Unitarian groups. They hold that Jesus pre-existed only in the sense of being part of God's plan. I believe this would qualify them as denying Jesus' pre-existence per the OP.

> "The Jewish worldview was that something planned (that is, foreknown
> in the counsel of God) existed notionally or ideally, but not yet in
> actuality upon earth in our experience. [...] When this paradigm is
> applied to those texts which seem to our Western understanding to
> imply that Jesus personally did consciously exist (as God) before his
> physical appearance on earth, confusion disappears." [Jesus'
> Pre-Existence - Literal or Ideal?](https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/articles/jesus-pre-existence-literal-or-ideal)

[Christian Science](https://www.christianscience.com/) (Church of Christ, Scientist) has ~100,000-400,000 adherents, and might seem to qualify as it holds Jesus is a man.

> "Jesus Christ is not God, as Jesus himself declared [...] Jesus is the
> name of the man who, more than all other men, has presented Christ,
> the true idea of God[.]" [Christian Science Beliefs](https://religionfacts.com/christian-science/beliefs) quoting
> Science and Health by Mary Baker Eddy

Christian Science isn't a creedal denomination (see [here](https://www.christianscience.com/what-is-christian-science/beliefs-and-teachings)), but the founder Mary Baker Eddy held to universal pre-existence in [some sense](https://sentinel.christianscience.com/issues/1948/8/50-33/pre-existence-and-unchanging-identity), referring to "man's spiritual preexistence as God's child". As the article continues, commenting on this:

> "Christian Science teaches that man's identity, his real being, is the
> reflection of Spirit, and therefore wholly spiritual, and that his
> existence as the child of God, who has existed with his Father-Mother
> God "from the foundation of the world," is eternal.

According to Christian Science, when Jesus said "Before Abraham was, I am" the 'I am' was referring to a universal Christ of man's true spiritual nature.

> "When Christ Jesus made the startling declaration, "Before Abraham
> was, I am," he not only referred to the eternality of universal Truth,
> but also to his own pre-existence as the individual son of God, an
> individual instance of divine reflection. It will be readily seen that
> these words apply to all the individual sons of God, just as they did
> to Jesus, the Christ." [Before Abraham Was](https://journal.christianscience.com/issues/1935/8/53-5/before-abraham-was)

So, it seems this denomination believes Jesus pre-existed, as all humans have in their 'real being'.

Comment: Your quotes from the Christadelphians and the CoGGC are the kind of unambiguous declarations this question needs, so good work finding them. Your quotes from the first two groups don't preclude a pre-incarnate existence, so it would be good if you could find more evidence about them.

Comment: @curiousdannii Good points - it's possible they hold Jesus is a man but also pre-existed. Church of Science isn't a creedal denomination. https://www.christianscience.com/what-is-christian-science/beliefs-and-teachings So my guess is beliefs may vary about whether Jesus had pre-existence.

Comment: @curiousdannii Added section confirming Iglesia ni Cristo does not teach Jesus' pre-existence. Also added discussion of Church of Science not being creedal.

Comment: No Unitarians in the list?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - check out the official Biblical Unitarian web site which says Jesus did not exist prior to God giving him life in the womb of Mary: https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/articles/what-do-biblical-unitarians-believe

Comment: @Lesley Yes, it sounds similar to the reasoning of Iglesia ni Cristo. However, BiblicalUnitarian.com isn't produced by a church, it's produced by a (I believe) fellowship. It's not clear to me if it counts as a 'denomination', per the OP.

Comment: @MikeBorden I believe all those churches listed are unitarian. No Unitarian Universalists included because the group seems to be so eclectic. Somewhat like Christian Science, but more vague AFAICT.

Comment: Oh.  So Unitarian is more of a theological school of thought than a particular church?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - Interesting.  Apart from Scottish Unitarians such as George Harris, described as a supporter of "old biblical Unitarianism", " in terms of denominations today which could be identified as "biblical Unitarian", the two most visible names are the Church of God General Conference (CoGGC), with 5,000 members in the USA, and Christadelphians, with 60,000 members worldwide." More information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_unitarianism#:~:text=Biblical%20Unitarianism%20encompasses%20the%20key,but%20may%20not%20be%20divine.

Comment: @MikeBorden Yes, two main theological divisions. Biblical Unitarian and Unitarian Universalist. Latter theological school is more or less a church ( https://www.uua.org/beliefs ), former has multiple churches and ministries.

Comment: @Lesley Yes, that article accords with what I can find, except they don't mention Iglesia ni Cristo which seems, practically speaking at least, a Biblical Unitarian church as well although it doesn't seem to use that label.

Comment: Upon further investigation, Christian Science holds all men have pre-existed. Moved to bottom of list and noted doesn't count.

Comment: @Lesley Added note re BiblicalUnitarian.com.